# Merging data on time column, but different "accuracy" of timedata

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different data. The data was recorded at the same time but one was measured only with seconds and one was measured with milliseconds. This gave me the two data frames:

**DF1**

```
TIME                Col1             Col2
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data     This is data2
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data3    This is data4
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data5    This is data6
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data7    This is data8
... (ten rows of time data at 08 seconds)
2021-09-27 14:23:09 This is data     This is data
```

**DF 2**

```
TIME                  Col1             Col2
2021-09-27 14:23:08.0 This is data     This is data2
2021-09-27 14:23:08.1 This is data3    This is data4
2021-09-27 14:23:08.2 This is data5    This is data6
2021-09-27 14:23:08.3 This is data7    This is data8
... (ten rows of time data at 08.x seconds)
2021-09-27 14:23:09.0 This is data     This is data
```

I want to compare this data by using the merge_asof method but as you can see there is a problem regarding the time data. One time column has a greater accuracy than the other resulting in the time data being unmergeable. Any ideas on how I can proceed? I have tried using the merge_asof in hope that it would merge time by index and seconds but this resulted in duplication of rows.

***DESIRED OUTPUT***

```
TIME                Col1             Col2          Col1.1           Col2.1
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data     This is data2 This is data     This is data2
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data3    This is data4 This is data3    This is data4
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data5    This is data6 This is data5    This is data6
2021-09-27 14:23:08 This is data7    This is data8 This is data7    This is data8
... (ten rows of time data at 08 seconds)
2021-09-27 14:23:09 This is data     This is data  This is data     This is data
```

My ideas so far is to perhaps add milliseconds to **DF1**. With other words, adding 0.1 to row1 and 0.2 to row 2 etc and then rounding **DF2**. But this would both be time consuming and inefficient.

```
from this import d
from turtle import xcor
from xml.sax.handler import DTDHandler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import os
import math
import glob
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


xcordi=21.551802
eq1 = -0.2094480490623*xcordi + 69.7792952182
eq2 = (-0.2094480490623*xcordi + 69.7792952182)+0.01

print(eq1)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)


#BLOCK GEOFENCE

max_x_value = 21.555706
min_x_value = 21.530232

datapath = r"C:\Users\a384663\Desktop\TASKS\LENNART\Piteå\Friction\Data_pitea.csv" 
outputfile = r"C:\Users\a384663\Desktop\TASKS\LENNART\Piteå\Friction\output_pitea.csv"

df1 = pd.read_csv(datapath)
#print(df1.loc[[]])
df1.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
df1['row'] = df1.index
print(len(df1))

df1['divided'] = df1['row']/21

df1= df1[df1['divided'].astype(int) < df1['divided']]
print(len(df1))

df1filt = df1

print(len(df1))
print(len(df1filt))

print(len(df1))

df1filt = df1filt[df1filt['roadeye_friction'].notna()]

print(len(df1filt))

print(df1filt.dtypes)

i=3
count = 0

df1filt = df1filt[(df1filt['Longitude'] >= 21.538851)]
df1filt = df1filt[(df1filt['Longitude'] <= 21.589464)]

df1filt = df1filt[(df1filt['Latitude'] >= 65.251439)]
df1filt = df1filt[(df1filt['Latitude'] <= 65.271148)]

df1filt['TimeUTC'] = df1filt['TimeUTC'].astype('datetime64[ns]')


df1filt['TimeUTC'] = df1filt['TimeUTC'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

path = r'C:\Users\a384663\Desktop\piteå\smaller' # use your path

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
print(onlyfiles)

filen=1
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\a384663\Desktop\piteå\smaller')


list_of_dataframes = []
for filename in onlyfiles:
    print("READING FILE",filen)
    if filen ==1:
        #try:
        #merged_df=pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='iso-8859-1',skiprows=43, usecols=[1, 19, 30, 31, 33, 83, 155, 157])
        merged_df=pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='iso-8859-1',skiprows=43, usecols=[1, 31, 33, 83, 99, 155, 157])
            

        #except:
        #    pass
    if filen > 1:
        try:   
            #merged_df.append(pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='iso-8859-1',skiprows=47, usecols=[1, 19, 30, 31, 33, 83, 155, 157]))
            merged_df.append(pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='iso-8859-1',skiprows=47, usecols=[1, 31, 33, 83, 99, 155, 157]))
        except:
            print("EXCEPTION", filename)
    filen+=1




print(merged_df.columns)

#all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")


print(merged_df.columns)

merged_df['99ea25ba-4460-4b0c-a99b-a8a180372037: Time_abs'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['99ea25ba-4460-4b0c-a99b-a8a180372037: Time_abs'], errors='coerce')
merged_df = merged_df.dropna(subset=['99ea25ba-4460-4b0c-a99b-a8a180372037: Time_abs'])

df1filt['TimeUTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df1filt['TimeUTC'], errors='coerce')
df1filt = df1filt.dropna(subset=['TimeUTC'])

print(df1filt['TimeUTC'])

merged_df.drop([44, 45, 46, 47])

df1filt.rename(columns={"TimeUTC": "TIME"}, inplace=True)
merged_df.rename(columns={"99ea25ba-4460-4b0c-a99b-a8a180372037: Time_abs": "TIME"}, inplace=True)

print(merged_df['TIME'])


#merged_df['TIME'] = merged_df['TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

(df1filt.assign(group=df1filt.groupby('TIME').cumcount()).merge(merged_df.assign(TIME=merged_df['TIME'].dt.round('s'),group=lambda d: d.groupby('TIME').cumcount()),on=['TIME', 'group'],suffixes=('', '.1')).drop('group', axis=1).to_string()
)

df1filt.to_csv(outputfile, index = False)
```

***IMAGES FOR ANSWER***

[df1 and df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCilp.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb0kB.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should probable provide the expected output as what you want is currently ambiguous

Comment: I am not sure `merge_asof` is what you need. It rather seems you want to merge in order of duplicates, no?

Comment: your edit is not really usable as it depends on external files. Try to minimize it to get where is issue is coming from. Have you tested my example?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it looks like you want to merge in order of the common times, not using `merge_asof`. For this you could use a de-duplication group:

```
# if not datetime:
# df1['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TIME'])
# df2['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['TIME'])


(df1.assign(group=df1.groupby('TIME').cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(TIME=df2['TIME'].dt.round('s'),
                      group=lambda d: d.groupby('TIME').cumcount()
                       ),
           on=['TIME', 'group'],
           suffixes=('', '.1')
          )
    .drop('group', axis=1).to_string()
)
```

output:

```
                 TIME           Col1           Col2         Col1.1         Col2.1
0 2021-09-27 14:23:08   This is data  This is data2   This is data  This is data2
1 2021-09-27 14:23:08  This is data3  This is data4  This is data3  This is data4
2 2021-09-27 14:23:08  This is data5  This is data6  This is data5  This is data6
3 2021-09-27 14:23:08  This is data7  This is data8  This is data7  This is data8
4 2021-09-27 14:23:09   This is data   This is data   This is data   This is data
```

input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2021-09-27 14:23:08', '2021-09-27 14:23:08', '2021-09-27 14:23:08', '2021-09-27 14:23:08', '2021-09-27 14:23:09'], 'Col1': ['This is data', 'This is data3', 'This is data5', 'This is data7', 'This is data'], 'Col2': ['This is data2', 'This is data4', 'This is data6', 'This is data8', 'This is data']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2021-09-27 14:23:08.0', '2021-09-27 14:23:08.1', '2021-09-27 14:23:08.2', '2021-09-27 14:23:08.3', '2021-09-27 14:23:09.0'], 'Col1': ['This is data', 'This is data3', 'This is data5', 'This is data7', 'This is data'], 'Col2': ['This is data2', 'This is data4', 'This is data6', 'This is data8', 'This is data']})
df1['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TIME'])
df2['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['TIME'])
```

Comment: Hm, this gave me only df1. It did not merge the two. Any ideas on what couldve gone wrong?

Comment: @Leo without a reproducible example, sorry no idea :/ Have you tested on the provided example? Also did you ensure your TIME is datetime type?

Comment: Hmm, then code perhaps is necessary. Ive updated the post!

Comment: I added my input for reproducibility

Comment: I have updated the question and added images to illustrate the problem